# how to find custom module in Pythonanywhere

Tags: python, scrapy, pythonanywhere

I am trying to deploy a webapp on PythonAnywhere that runs a scrapy spider when a name is submitted (the URL it scrapes depends on this name). The name of my scrapy project is 'scraperra'. The webapp itself runs properly but when the name is submitted (and thus the spider should start crawling) I get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scraperra' in the server log. This is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/AZServices/.virtualenvs/venv/bin/scrapy", line 8, in <module>
        sys.exit(execute())
    File "/home/AZServices/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.10/site- 
        packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 125, in execute
        settings = get_project_settings()
    File "/home/AZServices/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.10/site- 
       packages/scrapy/utils/project.py", line 71, in get_project_settings
       settings.setmodule(settings_module_path, priority="project")
    File "/home/AZServices/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.10/site- 
       packages/scrapy/settings/__init__.py", line 316, in setmodule
        module = import_module(module)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scraperra'
```

my project structure is as follows:

```
- webapp_bullit
   - mysite
      - mysite
         - __init__.py
         - asgi.py
         - settings.py
         - urls.py
         - wsgi.py
      - scraperra
         - spiders
            - __init__.py
            - artistspider.py
         - __init__.py
         - items.py
         - other scrapy stuff....
      - website
         - migrations
         - static
         - more files and folders
```

And I have the following in my wsgi file on pythonanywhere:

```
path = '/home/AZServices/webapp_bullit/mysite'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, path)



os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'
os.environ["PATH"] = "/home/AZServices/.virtualenvs/venv/bin/" + os.pathsep + os.environ["PATH"]
```

(The last line is to solve the error that the module scrapy was not found.)

How can I get the module scraperra to be found properly?

Comment: You appear to be calling scrapy as an external program. You will need to configure the python path for that program independently of the web app itself.

Comment: @Glenn Should i use sys.path.append(path_to_scrapy_project) in the wsgi file?

Comment: How are you calling the scrapy program from within your website's code?  It's likely that you'll need to set the PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Comment: @Giles, I use a subprocess. Popen, to be exact. However, I am now trying Crawlerrunner and seems to be working better.